# How to remove a .dll that is being loaded in .pyd file

Tags: python, c++, dll, importerror, pyd

I have many c++ built applcations that are being exposed later to a .pyd file .
The .pyd that is loading this dll files is used later in python .
I want sometimes to remove on of the dll and not use its functions .
The problem is that when I remove the dll , pythons shows an importation error .
importerror: dll load failed while importing mtf_pybinder.

I can't see what is the real error when the pyd is trying to load the dll in order to prevent it .
Thanks .

remove the .dll and don't show any error if it's not used .